# Excel 2010 - Do Not Display 0 in Index Match formula

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I am using an Index/Match formula in much the same way as a VLOOKUP formula, except that the data I want the formula to return is on the left of the data I'm comparing.

The formula is working as expected, but in places where there are blanks, I'm getting 0s in my form. I'd like to eliminate the 0s from my sheet.

I've already tried doing an array formula but I don't quite understand it and it also made my Excel die.

I've also done a Mode(Len(, even.

IFERROR also doesn't change the 0s.

=INDEX(Sheet3!A:A,MATCH(Sheet4!B:B,Sheet3!B:B,0))

On Sheet3, I have a bunch IP addresses (on Column B) and Hostnames (Column A). However, not all of the IP addresses have hostnames. Sheet 4 has the IP addresses and some other data, but no hostnames. In order to make comparison easier, I'm including the hostnames from Sheet 3 onto Sheet 4. But, where Sheet 3 doesn't have host names, I just have 0s in Sheet 4. I'd like to have the 0s changed to blanks or I'd like the formula to skip the blanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually solve that problem by doing:

`IF(index-match-formula = 0,"",index-match-formula)`

Which will return an empty string when the result of the index match gives 0. If not, it will return the value.

(Replace *index-match-formula* with your  entire formula)

Comment: OH DAMN. I completely forgot about that. I actually had to do that before and I completely forgot until you just said it! Thanks for reminding me!